# Vendor bake plugin function definition changes

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x, cakephp-bake

A colleague is cloning a repo and getting the following error when running bake commands through our own plugin:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of OurPlugin\Command\ModelCommand::findBelongsTo(Cake\ORM\Table $model, array $associations): array must be compatible with Bake\Command\ModelCommand::findBelongsTo(Cake\ORM\Table $model, array $associations, ?Cake\Console\Arguments $args = null): array in C:\Users\colleague_name_here\Downloads\xampp_php81\htdocs\OurApp\plugins\OurPlugin\src\Command\ModelCommand.php on line 334
```

I don't get that issue with my existing local copy. I was able to replicate cloning and duplicating to another folder. Where is that vendor change coming from?

In `composer.json`:

```
"cakephp/bake": "^2.3",
```

vendor file, where the function definition seems to have changed

```
public function findBelongsTo(Table $model, array $associations, ?Arguments $args = null): array
```

Current plugin:

```
public function findBelongsTo(Table $model, array $associations): array
```

In GitHub, https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/2.3.0/src/Command/ModelCommand.php

```
public function findBelongsTo(Table $model, array $associations): array
```

Comment: This arg was introduced _after_ 2.3.0. Note that `^2.3.0` doesn't mean "exactly 2.3.0", so you're likely getting a more recent version. Also, it's possible your colleague is using PHP 8.0 or later, while you're on 7.4 or earlier. At 8.0, non-matching signatures went from warning to fatal.

Comment: @alexHowansky we're all on PHP 8.1.10. I've been developing this app for close to 2 years, have had a few developers come and go without this issue arising. I'm deploying to Azure, and my latest deployment done Monday, isn't featuring this issue. Very strange.

Comment: In order to get this message, you need to be on PHP 8+ and cakephp/bake 2.9.0+. Perhaps you have a `composer.lock` that's locked to 2.8.0 or earlier and that's what everybody else is using, and that's what you deployed, so everything worked fine -- but your colleague just ran a `composer update` which brought them to the offending version 2.9.3.

Comment: The lock file indicates CakePHP 4.3.10, Bake 2.8.2. If I hard code CakePHP 4.3.10 and Bake 2.3.0, I see:  - Removing brick/varexporter (0.3.7), - Downgrading cakephp/bake (2.8.2 => 2.3.0). I get a different function definition issue.

Comment: [2.3.0](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/2.3.0/src/Command/ModelCommand.php) and [2.8.2](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/2.8.2/src/Command/ModelCommand.php) both have `(Table $model, array $associations)` as the definition. The extra arg comes from [2.9.3](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/2.9.3/src/Command/ModelCommand.php). So if you do `composer install` you'll get 2.8.2 and you'll be fine, but if you do `composer update` you'll get 2.9.3 and you'll break.

Comment: Until the code is adjusted, you might update your `composer.json` to specifically lock at the last working version `"cakephp/bake": "2.8.3",` and then even a `composer update` won't go past that.

Comment: @alexhowansky That worked! If you provide an answer, I can quickly mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This third argument was introduced in bake 2.9.0. Perhaps you have a `composer.lock` that's locked to 2.8.0 or earlier and that's what everybody else is using, and that's what you deployed, so everything worked fine when you do `composer install` -- but your colleague just ran a `composer update` which brought them to the offending version 2.9.3.

Until the code is adjusted, you're probably best off just updating your `composer.json` to specifically lock at exactly the last known working version, and then even a `composer update` won't go past that:

```
"cakephp/bake": "2.8.3"
```

Once you get the code updated appropriately, change this to require 2.9.3 at a minimum and do `composer update` again:

```
"cakephp/bake": "^2.9.3"
```